# Graphing with Pyqt and using data from mysql

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I would like to make a real time graph in pyqt using data from a mysql table, but i am not sure how. The table will be updated every second and will have CPU percentages (ex. 2.5, 3.5, 4.5). I am not sure how to make a realtime graph witht the data from mysql.

I have made a simple matplotlib graph below. I tried to incorporate the mysql data but i am unable to fit the needs of this real time graph.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import psutil as p

# Total number of iterations
MAXITERS = 2000
class CPUMonitor(FigureCanvas):
    """Matplotlib Figure widget to display CPU utilization"""
    def __init__(self):
        # save the current CPU info (used by updating algorithm)
        self.before = self.prepare_cpu_usage()
        # first image setup
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        # set specific limits for X and Y axes
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 2000)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        # and disable figure-wide autoscale
        self.ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
        # generates first "empty" plots
        self.user, self.nice, self.sys, self.idle =[], [], [], []
        self.l_user, = self.ax.plot([],self.user, label='User %')
        self.l_nice, = self.ax.plot([],self.nice, label='Nice %')
        self.l_sys, = self.ax.plot([],self.sys, label='Sys %')
        self.l_idle, = self.ax.plot([],self.idle, label='Idle %')
        # add legend to plot
        self.ax.legend()
        # force a redraw of the Figure
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        # initialize the iteration counter
        self.cnt = 0
        # call the update method (to speed-up visualization)
        self.timerEvent(None)
        # start timer, trigger event every 1000 millisecs (=1sec)
        self.timer = self.startTimer(1000)
    def prepare_cpu_usage(self):
        """helper function to return CPU usage info"""
        # get the CPU times using psutil module
        t = p.cpu_times()
        # return only the values we're interested in
        if hasattr(t, 'nice'):
            return [t.user, t.nice, t.system, t.idle]
        else:
            # special case focr Windows, without 'nice' value
            return [t.user, 0, t.system, t.idle]
    def get_cpu_usage(self):
        """Compute CPU usage comparing previous and current measurements"""
        # take the current CPU usage information
        now = self.prepare_cpu_usage()
        # compute delta between current and previous measurements
        delta = [now[i]-self.before[i] for i in range(len(now))]
        # compute the total (needed for percentages calculation)
        total = sum(delta)
        # save the current measurement to before object
        self.before = now
        # return the percentage of CPU usage for our 4 categories
        return [(100.0*dt)/total for dt in delta]
    def timerEvent(self, evt):
        # get the cpu percentage usage
        result = self.get_cpu_usage()
        # append new data to the datasets
        self.user.append(result[0])
        self.nice.append(result[1])
        self.sys.append( result[2])
        self.idle.append(result[3])
        # update lines data using the lists with new data
        self.l_user.set_data(range(len(self.user)), self.user)
        self.l_nice.set_data(range(len(self.nice)), self.nice)
        self.l_sys.set_data( range(len(self.sys)), self.sys)
        self.l_idle.set_data(range(len(self.idle)), self.idle)
        # force a redraw of the Figure
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        if self.cnt == MAXITERS:
            # stop the timer
            self.killTimer(self.timer)
        else:
           #else, we increment the counter
           self.cnt += 1
# create the GUI application
widget = CPUMonitor()
widget.setWindowTitle("30 Seconds of CPU Usage Updated in RealTime")
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run this in an infinite loop. The loop keeps checking the table every second, and then draws the matplotlib graph all over again each time.

It's not a very efficient solution though.